# Attaching a persistent volume claim is taking more time to a pod

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims

I am trying to test the time taken for attaching the Persistence Volume claim to the Pod every time it is created and it is taking time between 16 seconds to 36 seconds in various test that I performed. This is in AKS. The --node-status-update-frequency is set to 10 seconds on the Node. Any idea why it is taking that long to attach the volume claim to the pod? is it something that can be controlled through some config or it is controlled by Kubernetes?

Comment: Yes, my experience is that attaching a `Persistent Volume` also takes around 25-30 seconds on Google Cloud and AWS, and also on-prem using VMWare. This is probably what it takes for the underlying virtualization technology, and not so related to Kubernetes.

Comment: Statefull Pod should be deployed as statefull sets that way you can reuse persistent volume claims. Running any statefull workload as a normal pod is not recommended.

Comment: Did you test with statefullset?

Comment: My tests are with statefulset and the purpose is to reuse persistent volume claims.